# How to solve this specific differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this differential equation: $y'' + 2y' + 2y = 2xe^{3x}$? Should I first solve homogeneous equation or is there a different method?

Comment: There are other methods to solve linear second-order differential equations. One such method is the method of undetermined coefficients.

Comment: What is the simplest way to approach this problem?

Comment: The "simplest" way is by inspection, but since you have to ask this method is probably unavailable to you.

Comment: @user10354138 Can you give a hint concerning the inspection? Where should I look to make a guess?

Comment: For instance inspection proposes $(e^xy(x))''+e^xy(x)=2xe^{4x}$ as a simplified equation.

Comment: @Naah No, you completely missed the point.  Just as in e.g. solving simultaneous linear equations, knowing the solution makes the task completely trivial, hence "simplest".  Now conjure up the solution by magic or by harder work with another method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use Laplace transform:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathscr{L}_x\left[\text{y}''\left(x\right)+2\text{y}'\left(x\right)+2\text{y}\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}&=\mathscr{L}_x\left[\text{y}''\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}+2\mathscr{L}_x\left[\text{y}'\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}+2\mathscr{L}_x\left[\text{y}\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\\
\\
&=\text{s}^2\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}\text{y}\left(0\right)-\text{y}'\left(0\right)+2\left(\text{s}\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{y}\left(0\right)\right)+2\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

And:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathscr{L}_x\left[2x\exp\left(3x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}&=2\mathscr{L}_x\left[x\exp\left(3x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\\
\\
&=-2\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{ds}}\left(\mathscr{L}_x\left[\exp\left(3x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\right)\\
\\
&=-2\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{ds}}\left(\mathscr{L}_x\left[1\right]_{\left(\text{s}-3\right)}\right)\\
\\
&=-2\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{ds}}\left(\frac{1}{\text{s}-3}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{2}{\left(\text{s}-3\right)^2}
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

So, we get:

$$\text{s}^2\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}\text{y}\left(0\right)-\text{y}'\left(0\right)+2\left(\text{s}\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{y}\left(0\right)\right)+2\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{2}{\left(\text{s}-3\right)^2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\dots\tag3$$

Now, take $\displaystyle\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(x\right)}=\text{y}\left(x\right)$.

Comment: I would prefer something more elementary.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more systematic approach than just the guessing method. Write the equation as:
$$(D^2+2D+2)[y] = (D-r_1)(D-r_2)[y] =  2xe^{3x}$$
where $D = \dfrac{d}{dx}$ is the differential operator and $r_{1,2} = -1\pm i$ are the roots of $r^2+2r+2 = 0.$ This is an example of a linear but non-homogeneous ODE and ask yourself what is easier than this ? Well, the canonical answer would be a linear and homogeneous ODE. So can you turn this into one? Yes, just think of what "kills" the term $xe^{3x}:$
$$D[xe^{3x}] = e^{3x} + 3xe^{3x}\implies (D-3)[xe^{3x}] = e^{3x}.$$

But
$$D[e^{3x}] = 3e^{3x}\implies (D-3)[e^{3x}] = 0.$$
This means that our original ODE implies the following:
$$(D^2+2D+2)(D-3)^2[y] = 0.$$
Now, this is homogeneous and factored already, so you can immediately write down the linearly independent solutions:
$$y = e^{-x}(C_1\sin x + C_2\cos x) + e^{3x}(C_3 +C_4x).$$
You know the first two are already solutions to the homogeneous part - so you can just ignore them temporarily and solve for $C_3, C_4$ to get a particular solution.

Note that this method does not rely on any guessing. However, "guessing" is still usually faster once you have done a few examples.